# Notice: Undefined index in php (validation)

Tags: php, html, sql-server, validation

I want to validate my form and i got this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: ReqQty in C:\project\user\requisition.php on line 180
```

This is my code :

```
    <td><label for="ReqQty">Quantity </label></td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="ReqQty" id="ReqQty" onkeypress="return numbersOnly(event)" onkeyup="ItmQty_Availability()" disabled="disabled">

<?php
          $strReqQty = "";
          if(!empty($_POST)){
              if($_POST["ReqQty"]==NULL){ //ERROR here
                  echo "<font color=red>Enter the Quantity</font>";
              }else{
                  $strReqQty = $_POST["ReqQty"];
              }
          }
?>
```

I got the error only for this input type while everything works fine on others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use isset to check if key in $_POST exists

```
<?php
      $strReqQty = "";
      if(!empty($_POST)){
          if(isset($_POST["ReqQty"])){
              $strReqQty = $_POST["ReqQty"];
          }else{
               echo "<font color=red>Enter the Quantity</font>";
          }
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `disabled`; if you want you can use hidden. from your `input field`

`A disabled input element is unusable and un-clickable.` means you can not use them. They send no value further

You can use `readonly tag` if you want to as i am using in my answer. (suggested by `@ghost`.)

```
<td colspan="3"><input name="ReqQty" id="ReqQty" onkeypress="return numbersOnly(event)" onkeyup="ItmQty_Availability()" readonly>
```

Check this

```
<td colspan="3"><input name="ReqQty" id="ReqQty" onkeypress="return numbersOnly(event)" onkeyup="ItmQty_Availability()" <?php if($condition==TRUE){echo "disabled=disabled";}?>>
```

Comment: much better to put it as readonly so that it will still have that same look as a textbox. and still be included inside the POST

Comment: but that is for the event when one of the input is inserted into one of the textbox in the form, it will delete the attr disabled and enable the user to input the data

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 whats weird is: why does the OP want to have an event of keypress when its property is `disabled/readonly`. doesn't make sense.

Comment: that onkeypress event is to make the data inserted by user is numbers only. the disabled is related to a jQuery event when the user pick the data from Autocomplete jQuery, it will enable the ReqQty field to be inserted. Else it will remain disabled

Comment: can you explain the if($condition==TRUE)
theres still an error

Answer (score 0):

You have to check isset() not NULL

```
if(isset($_POST["ReqQty"]) && $_POST["ReqQty"]=="" )
```

Comment: but after that, it won't display the error code "Enter the Quantity" ?

Comment: if the $_POST['ReqQty'] not set, use if(!isset($_POST['ReqQty']))

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the field is not present on the request, so you dont have a `ReqQty` key on `$_POST`. To prevent that, you must check if the key is present, then validate it.

A nicer way to check would be:

```
if (!isset($_POST["ReqQty"]) || !$_POST["ReqQty"]) {
    // error
}
```